# Geocoding and Address Validation by Bing and Google

Tags: c#, geocoding

i want to validate an address and i have got two options Bing and google can any one suggest which can validate better.
thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very broad question. Both are equally good - check all the future features that you would require and the pricing. Pick the one which suits you most.

Answer (score 0):

Which country are your addresses in? I've found Google works well for US addresses, not so well for international.